# How can I use the ngClass with data binding?

Tags: angular

I need to use a Bootstrap class, making use of Angular's `ngClass` directive, but using Data binding, when I intend to use `stock.in_stock` when it is less than `stock.minimum_stock` the `ngClass` marks incorrectly, but if I use `stock.in_stock` and I compare it with a flat value, there is no problem.

What I intend is to mark or show the user which product is equal to or below a minimum stock declared by the same.

**IMAGE**
[image]

**CODE**

```
<tr *ngFor="let stock of inventory | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: page }, index as id "
                        [ngClass]="{ 'bg-warning': stock.in_stock <= stock.minimum_stock }">
                      <td>{{id+1}}</td>
                      <td>{{stock.product_name}}</td>
                      <td class="text-center">
                        {{stock.in_stock}}
                        <span *ngIf="stock.in_stock < stock.minimum_stock">
                          <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle" placement="bottom" ngbTooltip="The product on your inventory is less to minimum stock declared."></i>
                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="text-center">{{stock.minimun_stock}}</td>
                      <td>{{stock.warehouese_name}}</td>
                      <td>{{stock.ubication_name}}</td>
                      <td class="text-right">{{stock.product_cost | currency}}</td>
                      <td class="text-right">{{stock.product_cost * stock.in_stock | currency}}</td>
                      <td class="text-center">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalConsultProduct">
                            Consult
                        </button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
```

As you can see in the image, the class marks a incorrect way. Because, the item two (42)is not less or equal than (5).

Thanks!

Comment: The code you have shown looks ok to me. Please create an [mcve]. I recommend using https://stackblitz.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `stock.in_stock` and `stock.minimum_stock` are strings instead of numbers, meaning it's doing `"42" <= "5"` which is true.

Try parsing them as numbers and see if that works.

```
[ngClass]="{ 'bg-warning': +stock.in_stock <= +stock.minimum_stock }"
```

or

```
[class.bg-warning]="+stock.in_stock <= +stock.minimum_stock"
```

Comment: Hi, look, it marks a error: `ERROR TypeError: "_co.parseInt is not a function"` and mark each wrong iteration (white, is not visible)

Comment: Sorry, try `Number()` instead of `parseInt()`.

Comment: @JosephWebber - Try `+stock.in_stock <= +stock.minimum_stock`. Global functions are not allowed in Angular templates.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Ah, I didn't know that. Using `+` would have been my last suggestion which seems to work fine (after actually testing the suggestions myself).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I generally bind to the class attribute

```
[class.bg-warning]="!!(stock.in_stock <= stock.minimum_stock)"
```

IMO it's a cleaner way of applying a class to an element. 
Using the `!!` will evaluate the expression to a true or false, and bg-warning is only applied if the expression evaluates as true.

Comment: at this point I would be looking at your css maybe some other styles are overriding the bg-warning styles?  everything looked fine in your first example as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method instead

```
[class.bg-warning]="stock.in_stock <= stock.minimum_stock"
```